# I am using drf, The main problem is that my view returns a empty json

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework, backend, rest

My main is that my view returns a empty json. I want my blogs with respective foreign_key user_id.

```
My models.py file

from django.db import models
# from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils import timezone
from datetime import datetime
from .validators import validate_allfile_extension
from restfapp.models import CustomUser
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser


CHOICE_GENDER = (('Male', 1), ('Female', 2), ('other', 3))

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    gender = models.TextField(choices=CHOICE_GENDER, null=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    
    class Blog(models.Model):
        title = models.TextField(max_length = 50)
        author = models.TextField(max_length = 50)
        description = models.TextField()
        date = models.DateField(auto_now=True)
        time = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
        image = models.ImageField(null=True, verbose_name="", validators=[validate_allfile_extension])
        user = models.ForeignKey(CustomUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        
        def __str__(self):
            return self.title
```

My serializers.py file

```
class AddBlogSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    title = serializers.CharField(max_length=128,  write_only=True, required=True, error_messages={'blank': "Please provide title"} )
    author = serializers.CharField(max_length=128, write_only=True, required=True, error_messages={'blank': "Please provide author"})
    description = serializers.CharField(max_length=128,  write_only=True, required=True, error_messages={'blank': "Please provide description"})
    image = serializers.FileField(write_only=True, required=True, error_messages={'invalid': "Please upload image, video or audio file"})
    
    class Meta:
        model = Blog
        fields = ["title","author","description","image",]
```

My views.py file

```
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
# @csrf_exempt
@authentication_classes([SessionAuthentication, BasicAuthentication])
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def blog(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        blogs_by_user_id = Blog.objects.filter(user_id=request.user.id).all()
        serializer = AddBlogSerializer(blogs_by_user_id, many=True)
        json_data = JSONRenderer().render(serializer.data)
        return Response(json_data, status=200)
```

My Response:

```
"[{},{},{},{},{}]"
```

It gives me empty json i want my blogs with respective foreign_key user_id.

Comment: please attach your serializer code

Comment: Please don't ever anymore copy-paste the same exact text into your question several times.

Comment: Hi kiran, i show my problem clearly with serilaizer file in answer tab please review it again. okk james

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worked for me best solution try it:

write_only = True is preventing the serializer from returning read values. Consider removing it from any fields that you want returned to your client.

Your Serializer Should be:

class AddBlogSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
title = serializers.CharField(max_length=128, required=True, error_messages={'blank': "Please provide title"} )
author = serializers.CharField(max_length=128, required=True, error_messages={'blank': "Please provide author"})
description = serializers.CharField(max_length=128, required=True, error_messages={'blank': "Please provide description"})
image = serializers.FileField(required=True, error_messages={'invalid': "Please upload image, video or audio file"})

```
class Meta:
    model = Blog
    fields = ["title","author","description","image",]
```

Now, It will return your json data

Answer (score 0):

Is `CustomUser` your `AbstractBaseUser` ?

Because `request.user` will return an authentifacted `AbstractBaseUser`.

Btw you can use `request.user_id` instead of `request.user.id` (you do 1 less query).

For your `view.py`, i will write this way :

- Using `BlogSerializer` instead of `AddBlogSerializer`
- Just `return serializer.data` don't need to `JSONRenderer()` because it's the job of `BlogSerializer`

```py
def blog(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        blogs = Blog.objects.filter(user_id=request.user_id)
        serializer = BlogSerializer(blogs, many=True)
        Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: It's AbstractUser not AbstractBaseUser

Comment: Now, It gives me empty json not solve my error

Comment: Did you have `Blog`  entries  in database ?

Comment: If i convert my queryset into json. It gives me valid json response but this json is not good. I want to get my data from serializer.data. PLease help me

Comment: Hi everyone, i show my problem again clearly with serilaizer file in answer tab please review it again. okk james